# How to create short URL for Contentful assets

Tags: next.js, contentful, contentful-management, contentful-api

I want to create a short URL for assets on Contentful,
like example.com/image/Image1.

Currently the URL I am getting from Contentful is a very long URL like
images.ctfassets.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx85514b430c28045a3b2930ebeXXXXX/abc.jpg.

Is there some settings/config I can do on Contentful to shorten this long URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a setting for changing the asset URL and unless you're willing to implement your own asset proxy, you'll have to live with it.

Comment: Thanks Stefan for the reply,
Could you please let me know how to implement asset proxy for this dynamically (I need to show the user links for all my assets as example.com/asset_name?
I also checked there is some embargoed assets in Contentful, but I am not sure how to implement this.

Comment: Afaik embargoed assets are not what you're looking for as they're a way to protect your assets from public access. As for a proxy implementation please ask another question, because it's derailing the conversation. But keep in mind, if you're proxying Contentful assets, you'll lose the CDN and there are probably more downsides. I'd only go this way if I really had to.